# Android Studio cannot connect to mysql

Tags: android, mysql

I am a beginner for android development. Recently, I tried to connect the Mysql from Android Studio locally. When I clicked into the app and connected to the Mysql, the app just stopped. There are the error messages.

```
Process: com.example.hasee.mysqlsampleproject, PID: 18544
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:383)
    at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrlParser.parseConnectionString(ConnectionUrlParser.java:141)
    at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrlParser.<init>(ConnectionUrlParser.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrlParser.parseConnectionString(ConnectionUrlParser.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrl.getConnectionUrlInstance(ConnectionUrl.java:179)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:201)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219)
    at com.example.hasee.mysqlsampleproject.MainActivity$GetData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:77)
    at com.example.hasee.mysqlsampleproject.MainActivity$GetData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:54)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

this is the `build.gradle`:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hasee.mysqlsampleproject"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}}
```

And there are my main codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GetData getData=new GetData();
    getData.execute("");
}

private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Connection connection=null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            connection= DriverManager.getConnection(DbString.DATABASE_URL,DbString.DATABASE_USER,DbString.DATABASE_passwd);
            connection.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}}
```

I also wrote this code into the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Plus, I also set the Mysql open to connect. But, I still failed to connect the Mysql.

Please someone tell me how to fix this problem.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Any reason you want a direct connection to your SQL database rather than putting a simple server up? Anyway, are you sure `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` is up to date?

Comment: I know a direct connection is a bad idea. But, I just want to figure it out and fix this problem. my Mysql version is 8.0.11 and the jdbc is also in the same version. Can you help me to fix this?

Comment: I finally solved this problem since i has changed the version of jdbc. But, here is my question that why mysql-jdbc-5.1 can work but not for mysql-jdbc-8.0?